# Image quality becomes bad when I set newDisplayMode for graphic device

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I have a small problem. I drew an image using `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, and its quality is very good. I set the screen to be a fullscreen window using :

```
device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
```

and every thing is good.

But when I set new display mode to the frame to make new screen resolution (which is smaller than my screen resolution), it resizes the painted image. And its quality is bad.

I used the following code:

```
  DisplayMode display = new DisplayMode(1280,768,16,device.getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate());

    device.setFullScreenWindow(this);    
    device.setDisplayMode(display);
```

Is there any method to solve this and make the painted image have the same quality when I set new Display Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question by setting the correct bit depth:

```
DisplayMode display = new DisplayMode(1280,768,device.getDisplayMode()
                        .getBitDepth(),device.getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate());
```